# Using the same package name on both Google Play Store and Samsung Galaxy Store

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, samsung-galaxy, package-name

We have an existing Android app in the Google Play Store, and now we are looking at publishing it to the Samsung Galaxy Store as well. The issue we have is whether or not to use the same package name for the Galaxy Store.

The Samsung [docs](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-games/recommendations-to-bring-your-game.html) say it is "recommended" to use a unique / different package name. Doing so also prevents [cross-store issues](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/UnityIAPCrossStoreInstallationIssues.html) with in-app purchases.

However, using a different package name also means that other integrations in our app that rely on the package name (such as Firebase, Facebook, Applovin, Adjust, etc) will be affected and may no longer work for the Galaxy Store version. (unless we configure a separate Firebase project, a separate Facebook app, etc.. which seems impractical).

Has anyone faced a similar issue before? What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest Solution:** is to use the same package name with different App signature (Key store) for each market, this will prevent cross-store issues. I prefer this way because it also prevent having the same app twice from 2 stores.